# Size of forbidden minors for treewidth

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, extremal-graph-theory, graph-minors

For any $k$, the class of graphs of treewidth at most $k$ can be characterized by a finite set of forbidden minors.

For treewidth $1$ and $2$, the set is of size $1$. Then for treewidth $3$, the set is of size $4$, and beyond that the size of the set grows very rapidly.

For a given $k$, is there a known upper bound on the number of vertices for the forbidden minors for treewidth at most $k$?

Comment: Wikipedia says "For larger values of $k$, the number of forbidden minors grows at least as quickly as the exponential of the square root of $k$.[9] However, known upper bounds on the size and number of forbidden minors are much higher than this lower bound.[10]". (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treewidth#cite_note-FOOTNOTELagergren1993-10) Have you checked this reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, an upperbound was proved in [Upper Bounds on the Size of Obstructions and Intertwines](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0095895697917883) by Lagergren.  In case you cannot access the paper, the relevant theorem is Theorem 5.9.

> If $G$ is an obstruction for graphs of tree-width at most $k$,
> then $|E(G)|$ is at most doubly exponential in $O(k^5)
> $.

In the same paper, Lagergren also bounds the size of a forbidden minor for path-width at most $p$.

> If $G$ is an obstruction for graphs of path-width at most
> $p$, then $|E(G)|$ is at most exponential in $O( p^4
> )$.